# Writing a python function to loop out the values of each id

Tags: python, json, list

Below is my json data. What I want to do is write a python function to loop out the values of each id. Would anybody please help me with this?

```
[
    {
        "id": "1", 
        "code": "111", 
    }, 
    {
        "id": "2", 
        "code": "222", 
    }, 
    {
        "id": "3", 
        "code": "333", 
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON data? In what form do you have the JSON data: string, Python list?

Comment: Thank you, Simeon. I have parsed the json data. Sorry, Simeon, I still   could not figure out how to input my code in comment. I have parsed the json data with json.loads() and json.dumps()

Comment: Thank you for asking, Burhan. Yes, I'm sure. its the output from: json.dumps(sortJson["aaa"]["bbb"], sort_keys=True, indent=4, skipkeys=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data=[{"id": "1","code": "111",},{"id": "2","code": "222",},{"id": "3","code": "333",}]
>>> list_id=[x['id'] for x in data]
>>> print(list_id)
['1','2','3']
```

Comment: Hi Ashwini, there's another question for this answer. I don't know why the output is something like [u'1',u'2',u'3']... why there are some "u"s in there?

Comment: that's true, i'm using python2.7. how can I remove those `U`? :-)

Comment: this might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/remove-the-u-in-ustring-in-python

Answer (score 3):

If `jsondata` is a Python list with your example data, you can do:

```
for item in jsondata:
    print item['id']
```

Comment: Thank you, Simeon. I tried this. But the console gives me this:  /n   print item["id"]/n
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: In that case your list contains strings, not dictionaries. After `json.loads` you should have a list structure with dictionaries, not a list of strings (unless, of course, the JSON data is a list of strings).

Comment: Thank you. you are right. I did json.loads() for the json that I just posted. then the loaded json works. Thank you for the right answer. My Friend!!! Have a good sleep!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If jsondata is a Python list with your example data, you can do:

```
ids = [item['id'] for item in jsondata]
```